# За что отвечает rb.velocity.y?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Учу Unity 2D, не понимаю за что отвечает `rb.velocity.y`, и какой функционал он выполняет. Не могли бы вы кратко объяснить, пожалуйста.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed,rb.velocity.y);
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: Скорость по оси `y`, это даже никуда смотреть не нужно, просто по названию видно уже. Ваш код создаёт новый объект скорости, сохраняя в нём предыдущее значение скорости по оси `y` и задавая новое значение скорости по оси `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed,rb.velocity.y);
```

Здесь объекту задаётся новый вектор скорости. Для чего создаётся новый 2-мерный вектор `Vector2`, в котором значение по оси `x` задаётся из ввода (с домножением на переменную `speed`), а значение по оси `y` берётся из текущего значения скорости объекта по оси `y` (то самое `rb.velocity.y`) Если знать английский язык, то можно даже не смотреть в `API`, тут все названия объектов и их полей довольно "говорящие".

Comment: Спасибо большое.